# Exception Type: NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

`Exception Type:NoReverseMatch` this error is occurring during clicking the cancel button on web site. this cancel button is for canceling the delete process of post.

searched everywhere but unable to understand the error. also made some changes some in code but didn't work.

```
path("by/<username>/<int:pk>/", views.post_detail,name='post_detail'),
```

**`views.py`**

```
def post_detail(request,pk):
      post = Post.object.get(pk=pk)
      comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
      context = {
                 'post':post,
                 'comments':comments,
                 }
return render(request,'posts/post_detail.html',context)


  class DeletePost(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.DeleteView):
    model = models.Post
    select_related = ("user", "group")
    success_url = reverse_lazy("posts:all")

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super().get_queryset()
    return queryset.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)

def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    messages.success(self.request, "Post Deleted")
    return super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

**`moels.py`**

```
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='')
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="posts",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
message = models.TextField()
message_html = models.TextField(editable=False)
group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name="posts",null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.message

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse(
        "posts:post_detail",
        kwargs={
            "username": self.user.username,
            "pk": self.pk
        }
    )

class Meta:
    ordering = ["-created_at"]
    unique_together = ["user", "message"]
```

**`post_confirm_delete.html and _post.html`**

```
{% extends "posts/post_base.html" %}

  {% block post_content %}
  <h3>Are you sure you want to delete this post?</h3>

    <div class="posts">
     {% include "posts/_post.html" with post=object hide_delete=True %}
     </div>

     <form method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="submit" value="Confirm Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-large">
     <a href="{% url 'posts:post_detail'  username=self.user.username pk=object.pk %}" class="btn btn-light btn-large">Cancel</a>
```

```
      {% endblock %}

      {% if user.is_authenticated and post.user == user and not hide_delete %}
            <a href="{% url 'posts:delete' username=post.username pk=post.pk %}" title="delete" class="btn btn-simple">
                <span class="fa fa-remove text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="text-danger icon-label">Delete</span>
            </a>
```

expected to `cancel` the process and go back. and also delete the post on delete command.

Answer (score 0):

In **Html Page**

**change this url**

```
by/username=request.username/pk=post.pk
```